# How to destroy/cleanup existing Controllers?

Tags: angularjs

While navigating from page A to B using `route.resolve` my functionality works properly but when again navigating from B to A I get mismatched anonymous define() module. Both A and B has different controller with same module .

Answer (score 0):

The $compile service provides the `$onDestroy` life-cycle hook.

From the Docs:

> ## Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by AngularJS at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> - `$onDestroy()` - Called on a controller when its containing scope is destroyed. Use this hook for releasing external resources, watches and event handlers. Note that components have their `$onDestroy()` hooks called in the same order as the `$scope.$broadcast` events are triggered, which is top down. This means that parent components will have their `$onDestroy()` hook called before child components.
>
> — [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)